# Affirmative action based on economic status

Tags: inequality, income, affirmative-action

The reservation system in India is based on caste. Similar affirmative action policies of many other countries are based on minority communities. I think Israel is an example.

Is there a country who reserves seats in jobs, university admission, etc. based on wealth of the people?

The only answer I found is India itself. Along with caste based reservation, India also has reservation for those with low economic status. It is called [EWS (Economically Weaker Section)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economically_Weaker_Section) which provides 10% reservation for the General category.

Comment: I think the economist Thomas Piketty discussed this idea in some of his books and is in favor of this idea. I don't know whether it is realized anywhere in the world though.

Comment: I've removed the word "dreaded".  It seems pretty clear that you are opposed to this policy - but clearly not everybody is (or it wouldn't be a policy).  By including such words you tend to generate more heat than light.

Comment: One possible reason that this is not as common as other kinds of affirmative action is that determining someone's economic status involves multiple variables that can be manipulated. For example, if you set a quota for "people with low-wage jobs", a rich person could simply put their money away in trust and take a low wage job for a year in order to qualify.

Comment: There are universities in the US, particularly elite ones, who charge tuition based on family wealth (student aid and grants also typically have income cutoffs).  Which led to some rich parents giving up guardianship of their kids to game the system: https://www.nbcnews.com/news/us-news/wealthy-parents-giving-guardianship-their-kids-qualify-financial-aid-report-n1036241 .  I'm not sure if any unis have a strict quota for low income admissions, but more and more are offering significant support for such students.

Comment: @eps and the problem with outright banning such schemes with broad language is that there are some children who really are estranged from their wealthy parents and need help paying tuition. A system for adjudicating such cases will need to distinguish between "child is estranged for purely financial reasons, no financial aid", "rich lawyer parents refuse to pay for their child to attend anything except law or medical school, let's find him an art school scholarship", and "child is truly estranged due to marrying someone his rich parents didn't like and is now literally destitute at 18".

Answer (score -2):

> Similar affirmative action policies of many other countries are based upon minority comunities.

Whilst on the whole true, not all are. One example that comes to mind was the reintegration policy of Germany after the fall of the Berlin Wall in 1989. Here, the economically disadvantaged East Germany was integrated with West Germany's. Although this is not called affirmative action - it is. The main difference being that it doesn't target a minority. The total cost of the measure, on some accounts, was around 2 trillion euros.

> Is there a country that reserves seats in jobs, university admissions based upon the wealth of the people?

Historically speaking, I would say most were. This would include Britain and the US where certain posts were reserved for the wealthy. In fact, historically speaking in Britain, you could only vote if you had a certain amount of property. For example, a survey in 1780 showed that only 4,500 people out of 2.5 million in Scotamd could vote, whilst in England around 214,000 out of 8 million could.

What changed this was an effloresence of democracy, a fulfillment of enlightment ideals that had been shaped by the rediscovery of Greek philosophy in the renaissance. And in particular, the rediscovery pf Athenian direct democracy and the attendant political philosophy of Plato. This led to a broad-based socialism that allowed many European states, no matter what their political party affiliation or ideology to sign on a broad-based democratic socialism. For example both the tories and labour supported the social welfare policies outlined in the Beveridge report.

However, in the late twentieth century a rear-guard action has been set in motion, generally called neo-liberalism and took as the point of reference Friedrich Hayek and Milton Friedmann who advocated societies driven primarily by the market. In fact, Hayek wrote a book called *The Road to Serfdom* which warned that socialism would lead to slavery. Quite incredibly he ignored capitalism's role in instigating and protecting the trans-atlantic slave trade for two hundred years and which had enslsved and transported 12.5 million African men and women. Perhaps because the slaves were from poor African countries and really not properly human.

Friedmann advocated a fundamental form of market-driven social philosophy. He takes it as axiomatic that the market cannot be wrong. Its due to the adoption of his philosophy that Elon Musk can be worth £300 billion whilst many people have been priced out of homes, education and health. When I got a university education, I didn't have to pay for it - at least directly. Today, students pay £30-40,000 just as they're starting on life rather than it being amortised through the population by general taxation. As though society does not benefit from having better doctors or better engineers. But then of course, neoliberalism doesn't believe in society, but only the individual.

Neoliberalism, by advocating market driven solutions is bringing back the notion that one's options in life - ie home, education, jobs and health - should be dictated by the amount of property one owns. Even now, it remains the dominant political philosophy of the West. So, I'd say that despite appearances, and despite their political heritage, modern western democracies reserve jobs and the education necessary for those jobs to those with wealth & connections.